# How to get from Sony Vegas to Pro tools 9

Tags: omf, pro-tools, post-production, vegas

I've tried AAF, exporting XML, exporting edl, and exporting avid compatable AAF, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way of getting the Sony Vegas session to PT9. bouncing down stems is not an option.

Anyone have any real world experience in this?

Comment: Give a little more information on the exact issue - what way is it 'not easy' to get it into PT9?

Comment: As in you have to purchase a third party app for 160$ to convert the edl, and even then it doesn't always work. 

Since you even asked the question, it seems you have no experience converting Sony Vegas sessions for use in PT for sound editing / final mix. 

Comment: The simple answer is... You can't. Don't edit on Vegas in future.

Comment: Nice answer.  Maybe it'd be nice to know that I don't edit in sony Vegas. I received some sessions in and I'm supposed to perform sound design and the final mix.  So as you can imagine ive been down this path before, and I wanted to source some answers. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that I have dealt with a lot and I am sorry to say that there is no easy solution. Sony Vegas basically doesn't conform to industry standards e.g. OMF. This makes opening Vegas projects in other systems a real pain in the ar*e. You have probably already seen [this from SSL](http://www.solidstatelogic.com/post/pro-convert/). I haven't used it personally but it looks like the best option if you are not willing to render stems. But to be honest even using this I have a feeling that it will take a while to tidy up the PT session after the import.

Unfortunately my solution is to bounce stems from vegas - you can do this really quickly using the in built scripts in vegas. But even this isn't fool proof as Vegas doesn't do a very good job at delay compensation with 3rd party plugins so beware of sync issues.

sorry for not being much help -

Comment: It's cool. Figured as much. The SSL solution is out of my budget personally and same with the AAT solution.  
Thank you for trying though.  

I wish Sony would try to conform to SOME standard. 